# how can I display the array data on html using angular 4

Tags: angular2-forms, typescript-typings

```
[[{"display":"karthik@celestialsys.com","email":"karthik@celestialsys.com","status":"online"},
{"display":"shiva@celestialsys.com","email":"shiva@celestialsys.com","status":"online"},
{"display":"a.kumar@celestialsys.com","email":"a.kumar@celestialsys.com","status":"online"}]]
```

I am using angular 4 and the issue i am facing : how do I display only the email in html using angular 4

Answer (score 0):

```
// .html
<div *ngFor="let a of testData[0]"> 
  {{a.email}}
</div> 

// .ts
 testData =[[
            {"display":"karthik@celestialsys.com",
             "email":"karthik@celestialsys.com",
             "status":"online"
            },
            {"display":"shiva@celestialsys.com",
            "email":"shiva@celestialsys.com",
            "status":"online"
            },
            {"display":"a.kumar@celestialsys.com",
             "email":"a.kumar@celestialsys.com",
             "status":"online"
            }]];
```

Comment: of type 'string'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Comment: Ok . If it is a string then parse it to json using JSON.parse(testData)

Comment: same error can you provide the sample code for this

Comment: your welcome you can select the tik element next to my answer to accept it as correct answer.